# Ventajas de procedimientos almacenados vs scripts

Tags: sql, ssis

estoy corriendo un proyecto de ETL para migrar información de una base de datos de un sistema obsoleto a uno nuevo. Hay un proceso que es bastante pesado, consume prácticamente el 90% del tiempo que dura la migración. Básicamente es una consulta a una tabla para determinar si un registro existe o no, y de ahí determinar si se debe insertar el registro o actualizarlo, pero estamos hablando que la comparación se hace en una magnitud de cientos de miles de registros en el origen, contra un millón de registros en el destino y subiendo cada día.
La consulta se ejecuta desde el proyecto ETL por medio de la herramienta de búsqueda de los proyectos ssis, en la herramienta esta definido el query que traerá la información, siento que es algo muy parecido a utilizar la herramienta sqlCommand, donde definías la consulta en la aplicación y esta la enviaba al sql.
Ahora bien, mi pregunta es ¿si convierto el query en un sp que sea llamado desde la herramienta de búsqueda del ssis, traería algún tipo de veneficio? ¿Sería más fácil para el motor de base de datos estar ejecutando un sp que estar recibiendo un query constantemente? ¿O es indiferente?
Les agradezco cualquier aclaración al respecto.

Comment: Como regla general, un query con problemas de performance va a funcionar igual de mal no importa en dónde lo ejecutes.  Lamentablemente es imposible darte una respuesta concreta sin conoce estructura de tablas, índices y la consulta.

Comment: Sí hay beneficios el convertir scripts a SPs, pero no es algo mágico que mejorará considerablemente el rendimiento. También trae otros retos y problemas que debes considerar. Mi preferencia después de muchos años de usar SQL Server es usar Procedimientos Almacenados porque es más fácil identificar problemas y administrarlos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El Database Tuning es una ciencia en sí misma. Prácticamente tu pregunta puede ser resumida en: *Si conviertes la consulta en un procedimiento almacenado (SP), existen beneficios?*

Por supuesto. Luego de su primer uso, el SP es compilado y el resultado es guardado en su forma ejecutable, lo que hace más rápidas las llamadas posteriores. También, el motor de base de datos recolecta información estadística  y planes de ejecución para que puedas analizarlos y tomar decisiones acerca de tu estructura de tablas.

Por otro lado, los SP tienen su propio contexto de seguridad, lo que hace su utilización más segura que estar recibiendo una query. Por ejemplo, como lo describes, cualquier persona puede editar la query dentro del SSIS y causar estragos; mejor creas un usuario de BD que se encarge de la creación y actualización de los objetos de la BD y así tienes control sobre lo que ahí está. Está también el beneficio añadido de tener la descripción de la query en un lugar donde los interesados puedan leerlo, comentar las actualizaciones, etc.

A como lo pintas, y como lo veo, sólo hay beneficios al pasar esa query a un procedimiento almacenado.

Comment: Bueno.. compilado o no.. si el query es malo, va a ser malo dentro o fuera de un SP... si no hay indices, que este o no este, no va a cambiar nada... y por ese motivo, las preguntas que piden opiniones no son contestadas.. podria decir todo lo contrario a lo que escribiste, y seria cierto tambien...

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo. Por eso el frame challenge.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con lo del query y con lo de los indices, pero no era el objeto de la pregunta, no estoy de acuerdo con que la pregunta sea de opinión, ya que en realidad es sobre el funcionamiento del motor del sql, podrían salir mil respuestas que los índices, que la estructura de la consulta, que las uniones que se usan, pero es desviarse del tema principal. 
Igual agradezco los comentarios.

Comment: Solo como actualización, el convertir mi query a procedimiento almacenado, representó un ahorro de tiempo de hasta el 90% en algunos casos. Un proceso de 65 horas paso a 4.5 horas. También se aplico optimización a la consulta, como bien señalan los colegas, pero si fue una ayuda sustancial. Gracias.

Comment: Listo. Hora de pedir un aumento